# print all line that match my pattern until last end pattern match

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file like below, I need to print all line that match my pattern.
used the below code but end pattern stops after the first pattern match, I need to print until last end pattern match.

Input

```
ed.02122021.101453
ed.02122021.195702
ed.02122021
ed.02132021.111502
ed.02132021
ed.02142021.181004
ed.02142021
ed.02152021.104017
ed.02152021.211701
ed.02152021
ed.02162021.100103
```

What I need to the below Sed command:

```
sed -n '/02132021/,/02142021/p'
```

to have below expected output?

```
ed.02132021.111502
ed.02132021
ed.02142021.181004
ed.02142021
```

Comment: `sed -n '/02132021/,/02142021/p' < your-file.txt` prints three lines for me. Is that not what you're expecting?

Comment: You've got a range: the first line matching `02132021` to the first line matching `02142021`. You've provided example input. Please [edit] your question to show us the corresponding expected output.

Comment: @ preferred_anoni need to print the line until end pattern last match, provided the sample output.

Comment: @ roaima added the sample output..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119823/discussion-between-renga-and-s).

Comment: If you want to notify someone, you need to use `@username`, not `@ username`. No space between the user name and the `@`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a matter of just having to be slightly stricter with your patterns.

The range that you want should end, not at the first line matching `02142021`, but at the first line matching `02142021$` (i.e., it ends in `02142021`).

```
sed '/02132021/,/02142021$/!d' file
```

or, equivalently,

```
sed -n '/02132021/,/02142021$/p' file
```

If your data has trailing spaces at the end of each line (as in the question), then allow for that too:

```
sed '/02132021/,/02142021[[:blank:]]*$/!d' file
```

---

The above would work for the data shown, but would fail if the lines arrived in a slightly different order.

In the general case, you would do something like this:

```
printf '%s\n' '/02132021/ka' "$;'a,?02142021?p" 'Q' | ed -s file
```

This uses the `ed` editor to print the lines you want.  It does this by first finding the first line that matches `02132021` and marking it with the `k` command as "position `a`".  This is what `/02132021/ka` does.

It then places the cursor at the last line using `$;`, and prints all lines between the `a` mark (`'a`) and the first line matching `02142021` searching backwards from the current (last) line (`'a,?02142021?`; `?re?` searches backwards).

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` to print the lines matched with first line containing a string that matches `Regexp1` up-to the **last** line containing a string that matches `Regexp2`:

```
awk '/Regexp1/ || prnt { hold= hold? hold ORS $0: $0; prnt=1 } 
     /Regexp2/         { print hold; hold="" }' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pbm can be looked at by printing all lines from first pattern to eof then reverse the lines using `tac` and then
printing all lines from second pattern to eof (=first occurrence of first pattern in the input), then reverse once again to recover the order.

```
< file \
sed -n '/02132021/,$p' | tac |
sed -n '/02142021/,$p' | tac ;
```

---

With one invocation of **sed**. If you don't have **GNU sed**, change the `z` to `s/.*//`

```
sed -e '
  /02132021/,$!d
  /02142021/!{H;d;}
  x;s/.//p;z;x
' file
```

**Results:**

```
ed.02132021.111502
ed.02132021
ed.02142021.181004
ed.02142021
```

Answer (score 0):

Robustly using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -F'.' '$2=="02132021"{f=1} $2>"02142021"{exit} f' file
ed.02132021.111502
ed.02132021
ed.02142021.181004
ed.02142021
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -F'.' '$2=="02132021"{f=1} f; (NF==2) && ($2=="02142021"){exit}' file
ed.02132021.111502
ed.02132021
ed.02142021.181004
ed.02142021
```